# R stack plot based on value

Tags: r, plot

I want to make a picture with R.
I have data like this:
3 Samples and 4 categories, with value A, B and C

```
      Sam1 Sam2 Sam3
Cat1  A    B;C  C
Cat2  B    A    A;B
Cat3  A;C  C    A;B;C
Cat4  B    A    C
```

I want to make a plot, with stack colour for the multiple value.
The output that I want is in the picture.

[image]

Can anyone help?
Thank you.

(This solved by Robert Hacken, Thanks)..
Another add-on that I want is add notes on the side
For G1 has note D1 on the side, and so on...
Is it possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmuP3.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With visualizations like this, I usually find it easiest to just draw them:

```r
dat <- read.table(text='Sam1 Sam2 Sam3
Cat1  A    B;C  C
Cat2  B    A    A;B
Cat3  A;C  C    A;B;C
Cat4  B    A    C')

let.col <- c(A='red', B='#5b9bd5', C='#70ad47')
# width of the space between squares; square side + sep = 1, so sep=.2 means
#   that the square's side will be four times the empty space
sep <- .2

par(mar = rep(0, 4))
frame()
plot.window(c(0, ncol(dat) + 2), c(nrow(dat) + 1, 0), asp=1)

for (i in 0:nrow(dat)) {
  for (j in 0:ncol(dat)) {
    # first row -- Sx labels
    if (i == 0) {
      if (j > 0) text(j + .5, .5, paste0('S', j))
    # first column -- Gx labels
    } else if (j == 0) {
      if (i > 0) text(.5, i + .5, paste0('G', i))
    # stacked colours
    } else {
      # colors for the current stack
      cols.ij <- let.col[unlist(strsplit(dat[i, j], ';'))]
      for (k in seq_along(cols.ij)) {
        rect(j + sep/2, 
             # rectangle's top goes down for subsequent colors in the stack
             i + (1-sep) * (k-1) / length(cols.ij) + sep/2, 
             j + 1 - sep/2, 
             i + 1 - sep/2, 
             col=cols.ij[k])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We could use `legend()` for legend but its customizability is limited and doing it by hand is not so much work:

```r
# legend top left coordinates
leg.x <- ncol(dat) + 1.4
leg.y <- 1 + mar/2
# size of the square in legend
leg.sq <- .4
# space between squares in legend
leg.sep <- mar

for (i in seq_along(let.col)) {
  rect(leg.x, leg.y, leg.x + leg.sq, leg.y + leg.sq, col=let.col[i])
  text(leg.x + leg.sq*1.4, leg.y + leg.sq/2, names(let.col)[i])
  leg.y <- leg.y + leg.sq + leg.sep
}
```

[image: Stacked colors in a grid]

To add a column with notes you can modify the code like this:

```r
par(mar = rep(0, 4))
frame()
plot.window(c(0, ncol(dat) + 3), c(nrow(dat) + 1, 0), asp=1)
col.labels <- c(paste0('S', seq_len(ncol(dat))), 'Note')
notes <- c('D1', 'note2%', 'D3', 'D4')

for (i in 0:nrow(dat)) {
  for (j in 0:(ncol(dat)+1)) {
    # first row -- Sx labels
    if (i == 0) {
      if (j > 0) text(j + .5, .5, col.labels[j])
    # first column -- Gx labels
    } else if (j == 0) {
      if (i > 0) text(.5, i + .5, paste0('G', i))
    # stacked colours
    } else {
      # colors for the current stack
      if (j <= ncol(dat)) {
        cols.ij <- let.col[unlist(strsplit(dat[i, j], ';'))]
        for (k in seq_along(cols.ij)) {
          rect(j + sep/2, 
               # rectangle's top goes down for subsequent colors in the stack
               i + (1-sep) * (k-1) / length(cols.ij) + sep/2, 
               j + 1 - sep/2, 
               i + 1 - sep/2, 
               col=cols.ij[k])
        }
      # notes
      } else {
        text(j + .3, i + .5, notes[i], adj=0)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: with notes column]

This is without the legend but it can be added the same way as before, just increase `leg.x` to make space for the notes.

Comment: Hi, the graph looks exactly what I want.
I add some question to add note in my first question..
is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `facet_grid` for that. Here is the sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame( 
  Cat = c("Cat1","Cat2","Cat3","Cat4"),
  Sam1 = c("A", "B", "A;C", "B"),
  Sam2 = c("B;C", "A", "C", "A"),
  Sam3 = c("C", "A;B", "A;B;C", "C")
)
data_long <- data %>%
  gather(key = "Sample", value = "Values", -Cat) %>%
  separate_rows(Values, sep = ";")

ggplot(data_long, aes(x = Sample, fill = Values)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack") +
  facet_grid(Cat ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free") +
  labs(title = "Grouped Stacked Bar Chart",
       x = "Sample",
       y = "Category") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Here is the sample result:
[image]

[You can check running code here](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/LPnyzlIssRD)

Comment: Hi, I need the output that similar to the picture that I give. The box need to be the same size